# Aligning equations in an exam document

Tags: equations, align, exam

i got an document with the documentclass `exam`. I want to create a worksheet with simple equations, each as a `\part` in an `\question` environment. However I want the = signs of the equations aligned. I tried doing this.

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{exam}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question This is the question
\begin{parts}
\part 1234
\part 5678
\begin{align*}
\intertext{\part\hspace{1pt}}\frac{12}{7}+\frac{7}{7}=&
%\intertext{\item\hspace{1pt}}
\intertext{\part\hspace{1pt}}\frac{2}{5}+22225+\frac{4}{5}= &
\end{align*}
\end{parts}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

However, this doesn't work. It gives me the following error: !

Package amsmath Error: Multiple \label's: label 'part@1@4' will be lost.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please don't post such fragments only. Provide the document you're trying to compile

Comment: You forgot a  `\\ ` after the first `&`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to align things.  The easiest is to put them into `\makebox`es of the same width.  The actual width doesn't matter as long as it is big enough.  Note the `\linewidth` is the maximum amount of space left.  The `\raisebox` is optional and purely esthetic.

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{exam}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage{showframe}% MWE only

\newlength{\samewidth}

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\setlength{\samewidth}{1.5in}% local to environment
\question This is the question
\begin{parts}
\part \rule{\samewidth}{1ex}
\part \rule{\linewidth}{1ex}
\part \raisebox{-\height}{\makebox[\samewidth][r]%
  {$\displaystyle\frac{12}{7}+\frac{7}{7}=$}}
\part \raisebox{-\height}{\makebox[\samewidth][r]%
  {$\displaystyle\frac{2}{5}+22225+\frac{4}{5}=$}}
\end{parts}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Just for my understanding: the [r] in the `\makebox` tag actually defines, that they are aligned right?

Comment: Yes, since that is where the = is.  If you want something after the =, add it after the end of the \makebox.  (You may need to use =\strut to get the spacing even.)

Comment: Nice thank you very much. You saved me several hours...

Comment: If you click the check symbol it will close the question (he said innocently).